# Netbeans Javadoc not found even when library has it defined

Tags: netbeans, javadoc

I have a problem with Netbeans simply not recognizing Javadocs in external libraries. I've gone into the library path and specified a valid javadoc path (Netbeans accepts the path without error). But even after re-building/opening closing Netbeans, I still get the "Javadoc not found" error for all items in the library.

I'm stuck on where to go since there is no error message, and I can browse the docs using a web-browser. Any ideas?

The version of NEtbeans is 6.5.1
The files are uncompressed in a directory that has been added to the the Javadoc tab of the properties for the library. The library works as expected.

I've tried clearing the Netbeans cache to no effect.

---

I got it working. I deleted the library, the re-created it added the Javadocs. Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Could you please be more specific: What is your version of NetBeans? Where are those javadocs located? Are they unpacked in a separate folder, in a zip file, in jar file?

Here is a working solution for NetBeans 6.5 for an example:

- Go to Project Properties > Libraries dialog
- On "Compile" tab press the "Add JAR/Folder" button and locate your library
- On "Compile" tab press the "Edit" button with your library selected
- Add path to either: a) docs folder of that library, containing index.html and the rest of the files; b) zip file, containing that libraries docs folder;

It should work without re-building your project or restarting NetBeans.

If you have created a custom library, it can be edited in a very similar fashion through "Tools > Libraries"

Comment: It worked! If not work for someone, verify if the doc folder corresponds to the `imports` route, example: `import foo.abc` shoud have inside `foo` the folder `abc`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds similar to a problem i had recently, turned out all i had to do was delete the cache to force NetBeans to rebuild.

If @slink84's suggestion fails to help, you might try @dr Hanibbal Lecter's method from [my question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873432/netbeans-php-code-completion)