# Why Netbeans stop completing my php code?

Tags: netbeans, code-completion

It seems that Netbeans don't know about functions like **mysql_query** and complete only globals like **$_SESSION** or **$_POST** and stuff like **echo** and **print** (don't know about **print_r**)...
Screenshot: http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/4290/clipboard03vr.png

Comment: this is basically a duplicate of my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873432/netbeans-php-code-completion

short answer: clear your cache to force netbeans to reindex your files