# netbeans - php code completion not working anymore

Tags: php, netbeans, code-completion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NetBeans PHP code completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873432/netbeans-php-code-completion)

At work I am using netbeans 6.9 on mac os x snow leopard and suddendly php code completion stopped working. Whenever I use the code completion shortcut netbeans just tells me "no suggestions" also it would be clearly possible to complete the function/property. Even within a class when I try to access a method netbeans doesnt suggest me anything.

I already googled the problem but I didnt find any solution. Does anyone else have this problem?

---

**UPDATE:**

**Clearing the netbeans cache** did it, like described in this answer: [NetBeans PHP code completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873432/netbeans-php-code-completion/874778#874778)

This question can probably be closed as a duplicate

Comment: This question does not really belong on here, please visit: http://netbeans.org/community/issues.html

Comment: Are you trying this in an open project, or with PHP file(s) opened directly in the IDE without creating (or opening) a project?

Comment: @styu I experience this issue in an open project (PHP 5.3).