# Netbeans: Autocomplete / Intellisense not working for self created classes

Tags: netbeans, intellisense

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NetBeans PHP code completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873432/netbeans-php-code-completion)

For classes that I created myself an which reside in my project, netbeans wont give me intellisense.

How can I enable this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seemed to be a problem with the cache. See a similiar thread for further information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873432/netbeans-php-code-completion).

Deleting everything inside $HOME/.netbeans/$VERSION/var/cache/ solved the issue for me.