# No code completion for methods in Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans

I create a function say

```
function testing() {...}
```

I start typing tes... waiting for the code completion menu to show, but it does not. It works for variables.

I also tested a quick class, no code completion on it either. Did I miss something in the setup?

Comment: http://netbeans.org/files/documents/40/1346/Using_NetBeans55.pdf

Comment: The ctrl-space does not work. The menu pops up, but it does not show any methods created in the file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NetBeans PHP code completion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873432/netbeans-php-code-completion)

Comment: Do you recommend anything else? I used to love ZendStudio 5.5, but the new stuff is crap. I am on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I also started to use NetBeans few days ago. And also used to code in ZendStudio and didn't switch because of its functionality or something.

In fact, I think NetBeans has a better code completion no only for PHP code but for CSS and JS too.

I installed just the PHP version and had no problems with code completion. Are you using the whole NetBeans package or just the PHP plugin?

Comment: Just the PHP version. Function code completion doesnt work. Object / method code completion does nothing. Only variable works.

Comment: I had kind of the same problem with a project in Eclipse. Setting the include path in Eclipse fixed the problem. Have you done that in NetBeans? I'm also new at NetBeans xD